# Apache: relative paths appended to current URL instead of added to basename

Tags: apache-2.2, django, url

I'm new to web servers, so please be gentle:

I've set up a new apache2 server on a Mint System (Ubuntu-base, which also means Debian-based). I've also installed a Django backend and the wsgi_mod extension. I'm just serving from localhost for testing purposes.

The Django admin interface (accessible with `localhost/admin/`) refers to its css file with a relative URL like `static/admin/base.css`. Now I see in my apache logs that the browser is trying to fetch it under the full URL `localhost/admin/static/admin/base.css`, which doesn't exist.

I was under the impression that relative paths are always resolved by appending them to the basename, not the current URL. (Which would lead to `localhost/static/admin/base.css`, which is where the file actually IS).

Have I thought wrong (and my Django settings are mixed up), or have I miss-configured my apache server? The following would be my 000-default file in site-enabled folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias 127.0.1.1
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot "/home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "/home/web/http/80/localhost/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog /home/web/http/80/localhost/logs/access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/web/http/80/localhost/lib/app.wsgi

    Alias /robots.txt /home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs/favicon.ico
    Alias /images /home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs/images
    Alias /static /home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs/static    


    <Directory /home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I haven't changed anything in apache2.conf, ports.conf, envar or wsgi.conf. For testing purposes, my .htaccess file is also empty.

The relavant (?) part of my settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/web/http/80/localhost/htdocs/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
ROOT_URLCONF = 'osmmap.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'osmmap.wsgi.application'
```

while this is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:    
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

    url(r'^test/', 'testapp.views.home'),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your static path to be host relative:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: This sounds promising. A leading / will put the path right after the hostname? So now just for curiosity: can I influence what is used as the host name? Something equivalent of `chroot` for the webserver? (e.g. setting `localhost/mysite` as the host name, so `/static/` would resolve to `localhost/mysite/static/`)

Comment: Not automatically as far as I know, you'd have to include that in `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: Now checked and it (the original problem) indeed works as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that relative paths are always resolved by appending them to the basename, not the current URL.

This is correct.

> (Which would lead to `localhost/static/admin/base.css`, which is where the file actually IS).

This is *not* correct.

Relative URLs are constructed by stripping everything following the final `/` from the base URL and then appending the relative URL. So `http://localhost/admin/` has nothing after the final `/` and would have nothing stripped before adding `static/admin/base.css`.

Therefore, the constructed URL `http://localhost/admin/static/admin/base.css` is constructed correctly.

You will need to have the application developer fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Seems my understanding of 'base name' was wrong. Unfortunately I AM the application developer.